# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and index.php shows nothing

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, foreach

I try to program a website using PHP, HTML, CSS but I'm a beginner. At first I programmed my website only with CSS and HTML and this works well. But, I have several problems when I try to program the same website with PHP, HTML. and CSS with MVC model.
[When I execute my website this shows nothing:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QYNa.png)
Also, I have this other problem:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Model code:

```
<?php

function muestra($DB)
{
    $categorias = NULL;
    $sql = 'SELECT id,`nombre`,`imagen` FROM categoria';
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $categorias = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $categorias;
}
?>
```

controller code:

```
<?php
    require_once(__DIR__.'/../model/conexioBD.php');
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../model/modelo_categorias.php');

    $DB = conexio();
    //$DB = conecta();
    $categorias = muestra($DB);

    include(__DIR__.'/../views/vista_categorias.php');

?>
```

view code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Categorias</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/categorias.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Principal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Categorias</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Carrito</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
    
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="paginaCategorias">
    
        <div class="grid-contenidor">
            <?php foreach ($categorias as $categoria) :?>
                <article class="categorias-llista" id=<?php echo $categoria['id'];?>>
                    <a class="categorias-titulo" href="#"><?php echo $categoria['nombre'];?></a>
                    <div class="categorias-imagen">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img width="300" height="169" alt="categoria" src= <?php echo $categoria['imagen']; ?>/></a>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

index.php code:

```
<?php


    if(!isset($_GET['accio'])){
        error_log("error");
    }else{
        $accio = $_GET['accio'];
        switch ($accio)
        {

            default:
                include __DIR__.'/controllers/control_categorias.php';
                break;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $categoria['id']?>` needs a semicolon at the end: `<?php echo $categoria['id'];?>` Same for the other ones.

Comment: @Michel I made the change that you indicated, however I keep getting the same errors

Comment: What is `accio`?  It seems like that has to be defined in the query string for the page to work. Try adding `?accio=$some_val` to the end of your URL

Comment: @dazed-and-confused i try add `?accio=deffault` in the end of my URL and this works correctly but if i try acces to my url without `accio=$some_val` my page shows nothing. Why? My page should show the same and add `?accio=$some_val` alone no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `?accio=val` to your URL.

In your index file, look at the `if`/`else` block. It's checking what's in `$_GET` and if `accio` is not set, it won't show your page. I don't know what that parameter is for and it doesn't appear to be used elsewhere in your code.

```php
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['accio'])){
        error_log("error");
    }else{
        $accio = $_GET['accio'];
        switch ($accio)
        {
            default:
                include __DIR__.'/controllers/control_categorias.php';
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Since `$accio` doesn't appear to be used, you can probably use this as your index.

```php
<?php
    include __DIR__.'/controllers/control_categorias.php';
?>
```